# Attach ContentDocument to record

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument

Maybe someone knows how to attach ContentDocument to record through Apex? 
I need to copy ContentDocuments (which are in Google Doc's, Notes and Attachments related list) from one Object to another.
I tried to insert ContentDocument and AttachedContentDocument but we can't do insert operation on these objects.
I can insert ContentVersion but don't know is there a way to attach it to record?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Is your existing data in attachment ?And you just want to re parent ?or totally move to content version ?

Comment: `ContentVersion` may be associated to an sobject via custom lookup fields

Comment: There is a content document link object you can use to connect content doc or content version w specific record, can't recall the specifics but was working on that a few months back.

Comment: See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm for details on content document link object.  For some unknown reason I have only been able to set shareType to V (for viewer).  All other values throw a restricted picklist error.

Comment: That is right, you can attach ContentDocument with ContentDocumentLink object. Thanks to all of you guys.